# Starting service 'ipsec' tries to run uninstalled OpenSwan instead of StrongSwan

Tags: services, ipsec, openswan

I installed [OpenSwan](https://www.openswan.org/) to setup VPN server. It was not enough for my requirements so I had to uninstall it. Later, I installed [StrongSwan](http://www.strongswan.org) to handle IPsec VPN.

Now all my StrongSwan configuration is complete but I am unable to start the IPsec service through `sudo service ipsec start` because it tries to start OpenSwan Daemon while my configuration files are set according to StrongSwan, hence everything fails.

How can I tell the `ipsec` service that I want to run StrongSwan, not OpenSwan daemon?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by downloading the source code to OpenSwan from its web site and running `sudo make uninstall`, which fixes that problem. However, it has created the new problem that `ipsec` is not a recognized service.